# Cascade Deletion through MSSQL Database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I want to delete an entry from my Database but it says it can't because another table has referenced its id. The table I'm deleteing from is:

```
Packages(packageID(PRIMARY), package_name, etc. . . .)
```

The table I want to cascade delete from is

```
PackageVariant(packageID(FOREIGN), variantID(FOREIGN)) //those foreign keys combine to make PRIMARY composite key
```

On deletion of an entry from PackageVariant I want to cascade delete the variants associated:

```
Variant(variantID(PRIMARY), variant_name, etc . . .)
```

And thats as far as I want the cascade to go.

Now I have an Entity Framework model setup and working correctly, I have the database setup and working correctly. So how do I go about changing both or either of them so that this cascade delete works?

I also have a PackageVariantProduct Database Diagram made.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascade delete is handled on referential constraint in the database so you just need to set up `On Delete` rule to `Cascade`. The problem is that cascading can happen only from principal to dependent entity. So if you expect that deleting (even cascaded deleting) from `PackageVariant` will delete either `Packages` or `Variants`, it will not work. You will have to use a database trigger for that if you really need it.